# Can I always use the Reflection API if the code is going to be obfuscated?

Tags: java, reflection, obfuscation, proguard

I found that there seem to be 2 general solutions:

1. don't obfuscate what is referred to through the reflection API [[Retroguard](http://www.retrologic.com/rg-docs-problems.html), [Jobfuscate](http://www.duckware.com/jobfuscate/index.html)]
2. replace Strings in reflection API invocations with the obfuscated name.

Those solutions work only for calls within the same project - client code (in another project) may not use the reflection API to access non-public API methods.

In the case of 2 it also only works when the Reflection API is used with Strings known at compile-time (private methods testing?). In those cases [dp4j](http://dp4j.com) also offers a solution injecting the reflection code after obfuscation.

Reading [Proguard FAQ](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/FAQ.html) I wondered if 2 otherwise always worked when it says:

> ProGuard automatically handles
>   constructs like
>   Class.forName("SomeClass") and
>   SomeClass.class. The referenced
>   classes are preserved in the shrinking
>   phase, and the string arguments are
>   properly replaced in the obfuscation
>   phase.
>
> **With variable string arguments, it's generally not possible to determine
>   their possible values.**

Q: what does the statement in bold mean? Any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With variable string arguments, it's generally not possible to determine their possible values.

```
public Class loadIt(String clsName) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return Class.forName(clsName);
}
```

basically if you pass a non-constant string to Class.forName, there's generally no way for proguard or any obfuscation tool to figure out what class you are talking about, and thus can't automatically adjust the code for you.

Comment: okay, that's to say that the String is not known at compile-time, or a subset of this case (i.e. whenever the compiler cannot figure it out).

Comment: correct. In fact the above sample could theoretically mean 100's of class that are loaded thru reflection.

Answer (score 2):

The Zelix KlassMaster Java obfuscator can automatically handle all Reflection API calls.  It has a function called AutoReflection which uses an "encrypted old name" to "obfuscated name" lookup table.

However, it again can only work for calls within the same obfuscated project.

See http://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/docs/tutorials/autoReflectionTutorial.html.

Answer (score 1):

It means that this:

```
String className;
if (Math.random() <= 0.5) className = "ca.simpatico.Foo";
else className = "ca.simpatico.Bar";
Class cl = Class.forName(className);
```

Won't work after obfuscation. ProGuard doesn't do a deep enough dataflow analysis to see that the class name which gets loaded came from those two string literals.

Really, your only plausible option is to decide which classes, interfaces, and methods should be accessible through reflection, and then not obfuscate those. You're effectively defining a strange kind of API to clients - one which will only be accessed reflectively.